# htaccess rewriteRule Fix

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have little problem on the here

```
http//site.com/detial.php?verifyID=$parametre
```

i want this like short url :

```
http://site.com/$parametre
```

how can we do?
thanks

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /detial.php?parametre=$1 [L]
# Error Pages
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

i am using this but giving 404 error
how can we fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detial.php?parametre=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ detial.php?parametre=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed the PHP

```php
header("content-type: text/plain");
if (isset($_GET['q']))
  echo $_GET['q'];
else
  echo "empty";
```

You can get the URL in `$_GET['q']` by the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that it will also check that the requested resource is not an existing file `!-f` or directory `!-d` in the filesystem